# Encapsulating html piece with something breaks css

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following html code:

```html
<div style="
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;">

        <button style="width:100%; height:100%" *ngFor="let value of squares; let i = index">
      {{value}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Which looks like

[image]

However if I encapsulate  with something else, for example

```html
<div style="
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;">

    <div style="height:200px"><button style="width:100%; height:100%" *ngFor="let value of squares; let i = index">
      {{value}}
    </button></div>
</div>
```

The grid breaks, it's like the css from the button dissapears

[image]

Could anyone please indicate me what's going on?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5wfurm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encapsulate button within div tag you have to move the *ngFor loop up in the parent node (div tag)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k7ce9y?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Just move your loop from button to div like

```
    <div style="height:200px" *ngFor="let value of squares; let i = index"><button style="width:100%; height:100%" >
    {{value}}
    </button></div>
```